# Integrating CUDA with Qt on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: qt, cuda

I am trying to integrate Qt with CUDA. I am working on Ubuntu 12.04. I already have CUDA and Qt installed.

I followed the steps here - 
['linker input file unused because linking not done' when trying to setup QT creator & Cuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517660/linker-input-file-unused-because-linking-not-done-when-trying-to-setup-qt-crea)

However it still gives me an error.

Here is how I did it.

I created an empty Qt project called 'CUDA2' in my home directory.

I added the following files

**cuda_interface.cu**

```
// CUDA-C includes
#include <cuda.h>


extern "C"
void runCudaPart();

// Main cuda function

void runCudaPart() {

// all your cuda code here *smile*

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

extern "C"
void runCudaPart();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    runCudaPart();

    return a.exec();

}
```

I added the following lines to the .pro file

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

TARGET = cuda2
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
# Source files for C/C++ compiler
SOURCES += main.cpp
# project build directories
DESTDIR = $$system(pwd)
OBJECTS_DIR = $$DESTDIR/Obj
# and C/C++ flags
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE =-O3
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE =-O3
# cuda source
CUDA_SOURCES += cuda_interface.cu
# Path to cuda toolkit install
CUDA_DIR = /usr/local/cuda
INCLUDEPATH += $$CUDA_DIR/include
QMAKE_LIBDIR += $$CUDA_DIR/lib
# GPU architecture
CUDA_ARCH = sm_20
# NVCC flags
NVCCFLAGS = --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing -use_fast_math --ptxas-options=-v
# Path to libraries
LIBS += -lcudart -lcuda
# join the includes in a line
CUDA_INC = $$join(INCLUDEPATH,' -I','-I',' ')
cuda.commands = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc -m64 -O3 -arch=$$CUDA_ARCH -c $$NVCCFLAGS $$CUDA_INC $$LIBS ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME} -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
cuda.dependcy_type = TYPE_C
cuda.depend_command = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc -O3 -M $$CUDA_INC $$NVCCFLAGS      ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}

cuda.input = CUDA_SOURCES
cuda.output = ${OBJECTS_DIR}${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}_cuda.o
# Tell Qt that we want add more stuff to the Makefile
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += cuda
```

I ran qmake to generate the makefile. When I click on 'build', I get this error -

```
13:33:35: Running build steps for project CUDA2...
13:33:35: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
13:33:35: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" -w
make: Entering directory `/home/alex/CUDA2'
Makefile:541: warning: overriding commands for target `Obj/main.o'
Makefile:538: warning: ignoring old commands for target `Obj/main.o'
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -m64 -O3 -arch=sm_20 -c --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing     -use_fast_math --ptxas-options=-v -I/usr/local/cuda/include -lcudart -lcuda    cuda_interface.cu -o Obj/cuda_interface_cuda.o
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '__cuda_dummy_entry__' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Used 2 registers, 32 bytes cmem[0]
g++ -c -pipe -O3 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -      DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -  I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I. -o Obj/main.o main.cpp
gcc -c -pipe -O3 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -   DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -   I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I. -o Obj/cuda_interface.o cuda_interface.cu
gcc: warning: cuda_interface.cu: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o cuda2 Obj/cuda_interface_cuda.o Obj/main.o Obj/main.o   Obj/cuda_interface.o    -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcudart -lcuda -  lQtCore -lpthread 
g++: error: Obj/cuda_interface.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [cuda2] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/alex/CUDA2'
13:33:36: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building project CUDA2 (target: Desktop) 
When executing build step 'Make'
```

I am not sure if the .pro file will work with Linux. Looks like it was made for OSX. 
Also, I don't know if the line CUDA_ARCH = sm_20 is correct. Is there a way I can find my gpu architecture? I am using an NVIDIA Quadro FX 380M

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: NVIDIA Quadro FX 380M supports at most `sm_1.2` architecture.

Comment: Are you on a 64bits operating system?

Comment: @pQB .. hi there .. i see that I am using the method on your blog! Yes I am using 64 bit. Sorry I forgot to mention that. By the way I changed  $$CUDA_DIR/lib to  $$CUDA_DIR/lib64 .. I guess this is what I need to do. It still did not work.

Comment: Did you got the same error? Did you do 'make clean' run qmake and make?

Comment: @pQB.. I finally figured out what was going wrong.. I had included the .cu file in my project in Qt - this was causing the problem. I removed it and it works now! .. So you are right. If I had just run qmake it would have worked. The only warning I get now is ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '__cuda_dummy_entry__' for 'sm_20'. Any idea why that is happening? Maybe thats not a warning at all. Thanks! Wish you answered the question so that I can give you an upvote and mark the answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, you had some 'common mistakes' on your .pro file.

First, the CUDA toolkit has separated libraries directories for 32 and 64 bits. So, you need adjust the QMAKE_LIBDIR as follows:

```
QMAKE_LIBDIR += $$CUDA_DIR/lib64 # for 64bits operating system
```

or

```
QMAKE_LIBDIR += $$CUDA_DIR/lib # for 32bits operating system
```

Do not include the .cu files as SOURCES in the .pro file as they are not compiled with g++. The .pro file of your question does not show this case, but you commented that the .cu file were in the project in Qt remove them.

Finally, to be sure all your changes take effect do the following in the QT Creator IDE menu:

1. Build -> Clean Project # to clean old stuff
2. Build -> Run qmake     # to take the .pro changes
3. Build -> Build Project # obvious

PS: As @aland commented, your GPU device compute capability is 1.2, so adjust CUDA_ARCH = sm_12.

Comment: btw .. I changed it to sm_12.. it still gave that line on compie output ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '__cuda_dummy_entry__' for 'sm_12'

Comment: That's because you do not have functions (kernels) to execute on the GPU. I think that message is new from CUDA 4.1 and above

Answer (score 0):

1. This is the problem:

   g++: error: Obj/cuda_interface.o: No such file or directory
2. I would *delete* all of your CUDA source and libraries, make sure everything is completely *clean*, and *reinstall* from scratch.
3. Here is a good guide:

   http://laurencedawson.com/ubuntu-11.10-and-cuda-4.1

   <= Assuming you already have Ubuntu and your NVidia drivers installed, then just reinstall and rebuild the CUDA toolkit and source.
4. Forget Qt and forget your graphical IDE until you get things working.

   Please reinstall and rebuild CUDA from the command line.
5. Make sure you can run "deviceQuery" from the command line before you go back to Qt and the IDE.

Another good resource:

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Getting_Started_Linux.pdf

Comment: I think my CUDA is installed correctly. I could build all the SDK examples and also got some basic code working. I am able to run deviceQuery.

Comment: @paulsm4: If you read the log more carefully, CUDA part is compiled just fine with `nvcc`. The problem is for some reason `qmake` tries to later compile the same file with `g++` and link resulting object.